# CORS error with react native app run with expo web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, cors

I'm trying to run my react native expo app in the browser with the expo web feature, which is a pain at the moment, because I setup the headers in both the front-end and back-end.

```
headers: {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
},
```

I'm getting this error in the browser:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://21c9-197-26-42-128.eu.ngrok.io/server/...' from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Has anyone ever solved this issue before ?

PS: I know that I don't need to setup CORS in a mobile app, but the goal here is to make it work on the web.
Also, this only happens with the expo web version

Request headers:
[image: Request headers]

Response headers:
[image: Response headers]

Comment: Share the full url which is blocked.

Comment: Sure: 'https://21c9-197-26-42-128.eu.ngrok.io/server/api_mobile/iphone_setpost.php?user_id=&action=search_recommendations&sub_category=&filter_data=&category=1&start=0&count=5', it's irelevant, as the rest are only query params, and it wouldn't work as the server is not deployed at the moment

Comment: Then it is impossible to see if needed headers are in place. Take a look at these examples for help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#examples_of_access_control_scenarios.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` does not belong in a request; it's a _response_ header. Is `https://21c9-197-26-42-128.eu.ngrok.io` under your control? If so, you need to configure for CORS and allow requests from `http://localhost:19006`.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I was testing Access-Control-Allow-Headers to see if it works.
I included the headers for a sample request and response if that helps.